# Can I invoke Excel.run() in a page hosted inside an Excel dialog (using office-js addin technology)

Tags: office-js

I'm writing an office-js addin for excel.

I have some code running inside of an html page:

```
    Logger.Log(`about to call GetActiveSheetID`);
    Excel.run((context) => {
        const sheets: any = context.workbook.worksheets;
        const activeSheet: any = sheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        return context.sync().then(() => {
            Logger.Log(`GetActiveSheetID returns ${activeSheet.id}`);
        });
    }).catch((e) => {
        Logger.Log(e.message);
    });
```

> Aside: Logger scribbles to the localstorage so it can be read back
>   elsewhere since the debuggers consoles don't appear to work very
>   often.

When I host this bit of javascript/html page inside of a dialog (using [office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialog?view=office-js)) I get these log entries:

```
2019-03-14T21:14:24.043Z    about to call GetActiveSheetID
2019-03-14T21:14:24.059Z    An internal error has occurred.
```

When I run the exact same page/code inside of a taskpane I get:

```
2019-03-14T21:14:47.162Z    about to call GetActiveSheetID
2019-03-14T21:14:47.185Z    GetActiveSheetID returns {00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

It APPEARS that Excel.run () doesn't work when hosted inside an office dialog? So the dialog cannot be used to modify excel spreadsheet data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only Office.js APIs that you can call inside the dialog are `isSetSupported` and `messageParent`. If you need other Office.js functionality, you need to pass a signal from the dialog with `messageParent` to the parent page and invoke the Office.js APIs that you need from the parent page.

For more information, see [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: Thank you. This fits with what I've observed, but is this documented anyplace, and likely to remain that way? @Rick Kirkham

Comment: I've edited my answer to point to the article that documents this. See the "Note" about a 1/3 of the way into the article.

Comment: Very good! I dislike the design choice, but this is clearly documented on that page. Thank you!